# Plotly : Use px.strip in go.figure()

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

**Question :** Is it possible to do the strip with go.scatter ? If not, can you help me in transforming my code with px.strip function ?

**Data generation :**

```
import pandas as pd
import random

rows = []
for i in range(0, 130, 1):
     rows.append([i+57, i+39585, [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100)]])
df_test = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Measure Number', 'Timer', 'Values'])
display(df_test)

rows2 = []
for i in range(70, 200, 1):
     rows2.append([i+57, i+39585, [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100)]])
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame(rows2, columns=['Measure Number', 'Timer', 'Values'])
display(df_test2)

rows3 = []
for i in range(170, 300, 1):
    rows3.append([i+57, i+39585, [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100)]])
df_test3 = pd.DataFrame(rows3, columns=['Measure Number', 'Timer', 'Values'])
display(df_test3)
```

**Plotly plots :**

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


init_notebook_mode(connected=True)         # initiate notebook for offline plot

fig = go.Figure()


for i in range(0, 130, 1):
    # Add traces
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[j for j in range(15)],
            y=df_test['Values'][i],
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(color="DarkOrange")
        )
    )
    
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[j for j in range(15)],
            y=df_test2['Values'][i],
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(color="Crimson")
        )
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[j for j in range(15)],
            y=df_test3['Values'][i],
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(color="RebeccaPurple")
        )
    )


fig.show()
```

**Plot output :**
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Mvr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1Mi.png)

**Image example to explain what I want :**
[[**From**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2QN0.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj0Lc.png)
[[**To**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdEkZ.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Waek.png)

Source of the example : https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-show-overlap-points-in-scatter-plot/24148/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to check the structure of the [example graphs](https://plotly.com/python/strip-charts/) in the reference, which can be found in fig.data. Next, I will add the px.strip configuration items from the [boxplot example](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-that-displays-the-underlying-data) in the graph object. Simply put, we are just making the box color transparent on a boxplot with strip. I am creating the code with simplified data as your sample data was large and complex. To group them, see references.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

rows = []
for i in range(0, 20, 1):
     rows.append([i+57, i+39585,
                  random.randint(1,100),
                  random.randint(1,100),
                  random.randint(1,100),
                  random.randint(1,100),
                  random.randint(1,100)])

cols = ['Col{}'.format(x) for x in range(5)]
df_test = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Measure Number', 'Timer']+cols)

df_test.head()

    Measure Number  Timer   Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   57  39585   47  8   49  80  30
1   58  39586   64  74  12  73  46
2   59  39587   21  95  38  35  85
3   60  39588   50  7   100     30  82
4   61  39589   3   84  93  86  9

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure()

for i in df_test.columns[2:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(
        y=df_test[i],
        boxpoints='all',
        hovertemplate='x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}<extra></extra>',
        hoveron='points',
        jitter=0.2,
        pointpos=0,
        fillcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        line=dict(color='rgba(255,255,255,0)'),
        marker=dict(color='#636efa'),
        alignmentgroup=True,
        showlegend=False)
                 )
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(0,5,1), ticktext=[str(x) for x in np.arange(0,5,1)])
fig.update_layout(height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified a little bit the code to make it work with mine. Have a great day.